# Castle Windsor Ioc Resolving Generic classes in the web.config

Tags: generics, inversion-of-control, web-config, castle-windsor

I have an interface declared as

```
IRetrievable<T, idT>
```

where T is the retrieved type and IdT is the argument passed.

How do I configure the castle windsor IoC container to resolve that to a specfic Implementation. Such as a class defined as

```
FooRetriever : IRetrievable<Foo, string>
```

I found an example that showed how to resolve a single argument generic:

```
<component id="FooRetriever" service="Namespace.IRetrievable'1[[Namespace.Foo, Assembly]], Assembly" type="Namespace.FooRetriever, Assembly" />
```

However I can't figure out how to to accept 2 generic arguments (T, idT) instead of just one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<component id="FooRetriever" service="Namespace.IRetrievable`2[[Namespace.Foo, Assembly],[System.String]], Assembly" type="Namespace.FooRetriever, Assembly" />
```